# Access permission for different users. Android

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent

Suppose there is an application in which 3 users are registered. There is avtivity with three buttons. The user enters the application and can click on only one button (for each user own button), and on other buttons can not press. Tell me how to implement this. The application I make through Firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup user authentication. You can read about that here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/

Basically, you need to create a user account and then take necessary actions depending on who the user is.